# PowerShell - ShouldProcess not working when called from inside Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add ShouldProcess logic to a script that deletes files on a remote server to I can use the -WhatIf parameter, but it is returning an error. Here is the function:

```
function testshouldprocess {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true]
    param(
        $server
    )
        invoke-command $server {
        Get-ChildItem c:\temp\ | ForEach-Object {
            if($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($Server)) {
                remove-item $_.fullname
            }
        }
    }
}
testshouldprocess 'Server1' -WhatIf
```

When the script is run, it returns error

```
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

as each file passes through the pipeline. If I change the code to

```
  if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($server)) {
        invoke-command $server {
            Get-ChildItem c:\temp\ | ForEach-Object {
                remove-item $_.fullname
            }
        }
    }
```

it works, but the WhatIf only executes one time for the entire directory listing. If I change the code to

```
Get-ChildItem \\$server\c$\temp\ | ForEach-Object {
        if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($server)) {
            remove-item $_.fullname
        }
    }
```

it works, but I would would much prefer to use Invoke-Command.

Is ShouldProcess not compatible with Invoke-Command?

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hazrelle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69758975/45375) provides the crucial pointer regarding the need to use the `$using:` scope in order for the *remotely* executing script block to have access to values from the *caller's* scope.

To fully support your scenario - both for `-WhatIf` and for `-Confirm` functionality, *both* of which are implied by turning `SupportShouldProces` on - you must:

- Make your remotely executing script block an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one too, with its own `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]` attribute above the `param()` block, and therefore its own `$PSCmdlet` instance.
- Refer to the what-if/confirm-relevant values from the *caller's* scope via `$using:WhatIfPreference` and `$using:ConfirmPreference`

  - Note that for advanced functions and scripts PowerShell translates the `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm` switches into the equivalent preference-variable values, using function-local variables; that is, passing `-WhatIf` creates a function-local `$WhatIfPreference` variable with value `$true`, and passing `-Confirm` creates a function-local `$ConfirmPreference` with value `High`.

```
function testshouldprocess {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
  param(
    $server
  )

  Invoke-Command $server {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param()

    # Use the caller's WhatIf / Confirm preferences.
    $WhatIfPreference = $using:WhatIfPreference
    $ConfirmPreference = $using:ConfirmPreference

    Get-ChildItem c:\temp\ | ForEach-Object {
      if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($using:server, "delete file: $($_.FullName)")) {
        Remove-Item $_.FullName
      }
    }
  }

}

testshouldprocess 'Server1' -WhatIf
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I was not aware that you could use the cmdletbinding() attribute in an Invoke-Command script block to create an advanced function, but it makes sense now that you explained it. I really appreciate your answers. You guys are what makes Stack-Overflow such a valuable resource.

Comment: I am glad to hear it, @GreyulaReyula; thanks for the nice feedback. Yes, it's not obvious that a script block can basically do anything a function or script does, but it helps if you think of functions and scripts simply as _named script blocks_, which is technically what they are.

Answer (score 2):

The remote server knows only the command you execute. Not the values from the remote caller. Try with `remove-item $_.fullname -Whatif:$($using:pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($server))`. See [Remote variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.1)
Another option is to specify `$WhatIfPreference` on the remote server and use that in next statements
`$WhatIfPreference = $using:pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($server);`
Then `remove-item $_.fullname -WhatIf:$WhatIfPreference`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the $using:pscmdlet.ShouldPrcess() syntax, but I get the error 'Expression is not allowed in a Using expression.'. What you said about the values from the remote caller not being passed makes sense, though.

Comment: +1 for the crucial hint re need for the `$using:` scope, but there are two problems: a minor syntax one: `$using:pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($server)` -> `($using:pscmdlet).ShouldProcess($server)` (unfortunately, `$using:` references require enclosure in `(...)` for member access), but, more importantly, the _deserialized_ `$using:pscmdlet` value _has no `.ShouldProcess()` method_.

Comment: +1 thanks @mklement0 for pointing errors. I don't have tested before posting. Your answer is really helpful.